# When the screen resolution decreases, the header moves out, even though I have width: 100%;

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

Please help! When the screen resolution decreases, the header moves out, even though I have width: 100%; I was looking for answers and didn't find it anywhere!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    ghjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhjhh jhhhjkhnkj
  </div>
</header>
<section>hgjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</section>
```

Comment: I took the liberty of moving your code example into a snippet.  Please verify that this represents the problem you are seeing accurately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the `width:100%`, you just made `overflow` by setting the child element width to greater than the parent element.

---

A possible solution, use `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:scroll` (determined by which effect you want)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    ghjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhjhhjhhhjkhnkj
  </div>
</header>
<section>hgjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</section>
```

Or use `overflow-wrap: break-word` to let overflowed content automactially go to next line

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

header {
   overflow-wrap: break-word;;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    ghjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhjhh jhhhjkhnkj
  </div>
</header>
<section>hgjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your expected behavior, you can do either of the two options below

Set [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) for the header to break words into a new line and preserve `max-width`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    ghjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhjhh jhhhjkhnkj
  </div>
</header>
<section>hgjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</section>
```

Or use [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) to hide/show scrollbar for the overflowed text

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    ghjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjhjhh jhhhjkhnkj
  </div>
</header>
<section>hgjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</section>
```